# HDP Sandbox IOException calling saveAsTable on DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, hive, sandbox

I am trying to run the example below that tries to create a Hive table from a Spark DataFrame. The code works when I call spark-submit with master=local but it throws an exception when I call it with master=yarn.
Here is the invocation:
spark-submit --class test.sandbox.HDPRiskFactor --master yarn   --name "Risk Factor" ./hdprisk-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Furthermore I created a table from the Hive console named "default.geolocation" but I can't see it from spark when I call show(). I tried to set the executor count in Yarn mode to 0 and that does not work either.
1) Why does the code work with master local but with yarn
2) Why I can't see the table created in hive from my spark code.

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
//    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
val sc = spark.sparkContext
val hadoopconf = new Configuration()
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopconf)
val csvDataDir = "/tmp/data"
//import spark.implicits._
val dataList = List(("geolocation", "csv"), ("trucks", "csv"))
listFiles(this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResource(".").getFile)
dataList.map(path => {
  val localFile = path._1 + "." + path._2
  val hdfsFile = csvDataDir + "/" + path._1 + "." + path._2
  if (!testDirExist(hdfs, hdfsFile)) copyStreamToHdfs(hdfs, "/root/", csvDataDir, localFile)
})
val geoLocationDF = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("hdfs:///tmp/data/geolocation.csv")

// Now that we have the data loaded into a DataFrame, we can register a temporary view.
spark.sql("SHOW TABLES").show()
geoLocationDF.write.format("orc").saveAsTable("default.geolocation")
//      geoLocationDF.createOrReplaceTempView("geolocation")

spark.sql("select * from default.geolocation").show()
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not configure hive context properly. So it was writing files to the root directory. The solution was to pass the proper config params:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/user/hive/warehouse")
  .config("spark.sql.sources.maxConcurrentWrites","1")
  .config("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy")
  .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
  .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
  .config("parquet.compression", "SNAPPY")
  .config("hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions", "3000")
  .config("parquet.enable.dictionary", "false")
  .config("hive.support.concurrency", "true")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```